# Delphi Spring4D IList memory overflow

Tags: list, delphi, memory, overflow, spring4d

I am using IList from the excellent Delphi framework Spring4D by Stefan Glienke.

I have a list IList and I refill this list many times during my application is run. So, after two or three hours I have a memory overflow of my list.

This is how I populate my list:

```
  list := TCollections.CreateList<TVisitor>;

  for i := 0 to dataSet.RecordCount - 1 do begin
        item := TVisitor.Create ();

        item.Surname := dataSet.FieldByName ( 'firstname' ).AsString;
        item.Name := dataSet.FieldByName ( 'secondname' ).AsString;
        item.Patronymic := dataSet.FieldByName ( 'thirdname' ).AsString;
        item.CardNumber := dataSet.FieldByName ( 'cardnumber' ).AsString;

        list.Add ( item );

        dataSet.Next ();
  end;
```

The Clear() method doesn't free a memory, so each time I fill my list the Windows Task Manager inc memory usage of my application :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your list does not free the `TVisitor` instances.

Create is like this:

```
TCollections.CreateList<TVisitor>(True);
```

Comment: OMG, it is so easy! Thanks Stefan. Now it works perfectly.